# structured data in c# to byte array and back to structured data in python

Tags: c#, python-3.x, unity-game-engine, tcp, mono

This is a long one, please be patient. I am trying to make an AI training loop between Unity3d(C#/Mono) and Python(Neural Network code here). Basically what will happen is that my C# script will send state and environment information of a self driving car equipped with 4 proximity sensors(sensor data, orientation in 3d world) to my Python code over a localhost TCP connection, and the Python will reply with the action to take(throttle forward, turn right, etc.) while learning to drive the car. I've got my basic connection set up, by mostly copying code from different blogs(I know very little about networking, basic understanding of TCP/IP).

My TCPManager Class in Unity:

```
public class TCPManager 
{
    private int PORT_NO;
    private String SERVER_IP;
    TcpClient tcpClient;

    public TCPManager(String ip, int port)
    {
        SERVER_IP = ip; PORT_NO = port;
        tcpClient = new TcpClient(SERVER_IP, PORT_NO);
    }

    public void SendReq(String request, out String response)
    {
        NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        byte[] toSend = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request);

        networkStream.Write(toSend, 0, toSend.Length);

        byte[] toRead = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];

        int bytesRead = networkStream.Read(toRead, 0, tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);
        response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(toRead, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    ~TCPManager()
    {
        tcpClient.Close();
    }
}
```

My GameManager in Unity is Something like this:

```
public class GameManager: MonoBehaviour{

    public CarManager carManager;

    private double trialNumber;
    private double totalTrials;

    static TCPManager tcpManager;
    private string dataToSend;
    private string dataReceived;

    //Initialization
    void Start () {
        trialNumber = 0;
        totalTrials = 1000;
        tcpManager = new TCPManager("127.0.0.1", 10000);
        dataToSend = "State0";
        StartCoroutine(GameLoop());
    }

    IEnumerator GameLoop()
    {
        yield return StartCoroutine(TrialStart());
        yield return StartCoroutine(TrialRunning());
        if(trialNumber <= totalTrials)
        {
            StartCoroutine(GameLoop());
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator TrialStart()
    {
        carManager.Reset();
        trialNumber++;
        yield return null;
    }

    private IEnumerator TrialRunning()
    {
        while (!/* Trial.HasFailed() */)
        {
            tcpManager.SendReq(dataToSend,out dataReceived);
            if(dataReceived == "FD")
            {
                carManager.MoveForward();
            }
            else if(dataReceived == "BK")
            {
                carManager.MoveBackward();
            }
            else if (dataReceived == "RT")
            {
                carManager.TurnRight();
            }
            else if (dataReceived == "LT")
            {
                carManager.TurnLeft();
            }
            else
            {
                carManager.Stop();
            }
            /*
            Write current state to dataToSend
            */
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And my Python Code:

```
import socket
import sys
from random import randint

#set up actions
actions = ["FD","BK","RT","LT","ST"]

# create socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# bind socket to port
server_address = ('localhost', 10000)
print('starting up on {} port {}'.format(*server_address))
sock.bind(server_address)

# listen for incoming connections
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    # Wait for a connection
    print('Waiting for connection')
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    try:
        print('connection from', client_address)

        # Recieve the data in small chunks and reTransmit it
        while True:
            # data = connection.recv(16)
            data = actions[randint(0,4)]
            data = data.encode('utf-8')
            print('recieved {!r}'.format(data))

            if data:
                print('sending data back to the client')
                connection.sendall(data)
            else:
                print('no data from', client_address)
                break

    finally:
        connection.close()
```

All of this seems to work. "State0" is a string converted to a utf-8 encoded byte array, sent to Python, which reads it, utf-8 encodes another string to byte array and replies to the game engine. But I want to send more than a string. Specifically, I need **dataToSend** be a struct like:

```
struct dataToSend
{
    float sensor1_value = 0.43f;
    float sensor2_value = -1f;
    ...other types
}
```

and have a function **EncodeStructuredData**(dataToSend) on the C# end and have it as something like **DecodeStructuredData**(byteArrayRecieved) on the python end which will return something like

```
data = [0.43, -1, ...]
```

on the Python end. Any kind of help, any library or directions on how to implement this myself would be a huge Help. Thank you all.

Comment: Use json or xml. That should be compatible between C# and Python otherwise you will have to do more work to get binary serialization. FYI, you may want to look into using Threads in your Unity TCP connect/send/receive code because your current code is doing it on the main code which will block Unity and slow down your game.

Comment: I'll implement the threading part later. I know the pitfalls of making network calls on the main thread in Unity. I need near-realtime update, so will there be major performance overhead in using JSON/XML vs Binary Serialization? I want the learning process to be smooth, and want the feedback to run as many times a second as I can. I tried looking deeper, and encountered Terms like Marshalling and InterOp, and got confused.

Comment: Google each one and see their differences. Json and Xml are larger in size than binary. If you want to send the data fast, use binary. I recommend Protobuf in this case.

Comment: I looked into Protobuf and it seems to be the thing I've been looking for. Thanks a ton.